# Checking which button user pressed and checking the button text

Tags: java, android, methods

I am a noob in Java and programing and I am making an app where the user is trying to guess a city based on a picture. The user sees a picture of the city and has three buttons under the picture with different answers in them. The pictures are randomized from an array and the buttons text changes so that atleast one of the buttons has the correct answer. I want a TextView with "correct" to show if user is correct and one with "incorrect" to show if user is wrong. The text is showing up when pressing any button and not when the button with the correct text is pressed. So this is what I have tried and am stuck on. And yes I know I have many mistakes in my code, such as names of methods and so. I will change these later.

I have three booleans that are set to false, they are representing which button is pressed. You will understand more later.

```
Boolean test1 = false;
Boolean test2 = false;
Boolean test3 = false;
```

In main i have three buttons and they all call on the checkanswer function. Also they all turn their own boolean to true there, which u will se why soon. Example of one of the buttons.

```
 btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            test1 = true;
            checkanswer();
        }
    });
```

So here is the checkanswer function

```
public void checkanswer() {
    DisplayRandomImage();

    //Giving three strings random city names from the "cities" array.
    Random rndBtnTxt = new Random();
    String randomCity1 = cities[rndBtnTxt.nextInt(cities.length)];
    String randomCity2 = cities[rndBtnTxt.nextInt(cities.length)];
    String randomCity3 = cities[rndBtnTxt.nextInt(cities.length)];

    //Setting the random city names to the three different buttons.
    btn1.setText(randomCity1);
    btn2.setText(randomCity2);
    btn3.setText(randomCity3);

    //takes the picked image from the "DisplayRandomImage" method.
    String str = String.valueOf(pickedImg);

    //Tells what to call the different pictures, they are known as numbers make sure they are given names instead.
    if (pickedImg == 0)
        str = "venice";
    if (pickedImg == 1)
        str = "new york";

    //If-statement checking so that atleast one button has the correct answer.
    if (randomCity1 != str || randomCity2 != str || randomCity3 != str) {

        Random rndbtn = new Random();
        Button x = btnArray.get(rndbtn.nextInt(btnArray.size()));

        //Sets one of the three buttons so that it has the correct answer.
        x.setText(str);
    }
    //See where the correct answer is
    String buttonText1 = btn1.getText().toString();
    String buttonText2 = btn2.getText().toString();
    String buttonText3 = btn3.getText().toString();

    //check if the button that the user pressed has the correct answer
    if (test1.equals(true) && buttonText1.equals(str)){
        CorrectAnswer();
        test1 = false;
    }
    if (test2.equals(true) && buttonText2.equals(str)){
        CorrectAnswer();
        test2 = false;
    }
    if (test3.equals(true) && buttonText3.equals(str)){
        CorrectAnswer();
        test3 = false;
    }
    else
        WrongAnswer();
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. For example the "test1" is set to True when I press "btn1" and if "buttontext1" equals to the same as "str" does it should work. But for some reason it seems randomised which of the three buttons calls for the CorrectAnswer method. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for answering the question, i have found a way to complete this problem:

```
public void testingMethod(int button){

    switch(button){
        case 1:
            if (buttonText1 == str)
                CorrectAnswer();
            else
                WrongAnswer();
            break;
        case 2:
            if (buttonText2 == str)
                CorrectAnswer();
            else
                WrongAnswer();
            break;
        case 3:
            if (buttonText3 == str)
                CorrectAnswer();
            else
                WrongAnswer();
            break;

    }
}
```

And since you were wondering how the method CorrectAnswer looked like here it is, yes I know it's probably unnecessary having this method but I am noob after all.

```
public void CorrectAnswer() {
    findViewById(R.id.txtIncorrect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.txtCorrect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can we see `CorrectAnswer`? Also,
right off the bat, I noticed that instead of using `test1`, `test2` and `test3` to indicate which button was pressed, you can just pass some sort of argument into `checkAnswer`, like `int button`.
So `onClick` would look like this for the first button, and subsequent buttons by incrementing the 1:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            checkanswer(1);
        }
```

and `checkanswer` would look like this:

```
public void checkanswer(int button) {

... (previous stuff) ...

    //check if the button that the user pressed has the correct answer
    if (button == 1 && buttonText1.equals(str)){
        CorrectAnswer();
    }
    if (button == 2 && buttonText2.equals(str)){
        CorrectAnswer();
    }
    if (button == 3 && buttonText3.equals(str)){
        CorrectAnswer();
    }
    else
        WrongAnswer();
}
```

So try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty hard to tell where the bug is, if you only show us pieces of the full code.
Mistakes could be  e.g. in CorrectAnswer()...

I would recommend binding onlick-listeners to your buttons instead of changing booleans. 
Check this out here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button

Additionally I noticed another mistake:

```
randomCity1 != str || randomCity2 != str || randomCity3 != str
```

This will return true if at least one of the Strings does not contain the right answer
You probably want to enter the if-Statement, when there isnt already a button with the correct answer.This is what you would like to use:

```
randomCity1 != str && randomCity2 != str && randomCity3 != str
```

EDIT: Check out the answer of Barcode for another example of using onClicklisteners.